# align grid lines on two plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2 subplots in matplotlib in Python. They are stacked on top of each other.

I want to have gridlines on each plot, which I have done successfully. But each plot has a different x axis and, therefore, the vertical grid lines of the top plot are not aligned with those of the bottom plot.

I would like the grid lines of the top plot to be in the same position on the x axis as they are on the bottom plot i.e. the vertical grid lines in both plots should be aligned.

I imaging that I can tell my grid lines exactly where to be, and so I could achieve my goal by adjusting the lines until they match as well as possible.

I just hoped that there might be some easier way that would just allow me to align the gridlines on both plots.

---

Edit:

I don't think the [shared axis](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html) stuff is quite what I want.

My top and bottom plot have very different scales, so when I share the axes, it shifts the scaling too. For example, say my top plot has data that runs from 0-100 on the x axis and on the bottom plot the data runs from 0-50. When I share the axis, the top plot only shows data from 0-50, which I don't want it to.

I want it to show from 0-100 as it did before, but just want it to share the axis and gridlines from the other plot.

Comment: Have a look through the matplotlib gallery, there are examples (with source code) that do just this.

Comment: But then the lines are more confusing than helpful, aren't they? If I look at a plot with multiple subplots having perfectly aligned grid lines, I would intuitively assume that the scales are the same as well. At least for me it would be rather surprising to find different values on the axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `LinearLocator`:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
```

Then on each of your x-axis or only on one of them call:

```
N = 6 # Set number of gridlines you want to have in each graph

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(N))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(N))
```

Or get the number of ticks from your source axis and set it on target axis:

```
N = source_ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
target_ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(N))
```